# Why might Mosaico emails with links with backgrounds sometimes not show in gmail (and possibly other providers)

Tags: mosaico

Bit obscure but client had this issue and while it showed in my Mac Mail, in gmail itself the links did not show at all - not just a case of white  on white, but absolutely nothing to click on

Answer (score 1):

Purely due to a typo the background colour was ##4f81bd (yes doubled down on the hash)

so clearly some email readers go 'doh, you put two and you only need one so i will ignore one of them and show what you meant to show', and others go 'two hashes, are you nuts! this will NOT be shown'

so now we know!